# How to limit natvis of a single char to only the character in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, natvis

When creating a

```
<DisplayString>{a_char,c}</DisplayString>
```

in a .natvis file, the char is being displayed as f.e.

> 82 'R'

I'm looking for a way to display it as

> 'R'

e.g. without the number.

Answer (score 2):

The somewhat expressive way to achieve this is to treat it as a string with length 1

```
<DisplayString>'{&amp; a_char,[1]nasb}'</DisplayString>
```

which results in f.e.

> 'R'